# Succinct way to create a tracking branch with Git

Tags: git, bash, shell

Today I had to work with a remote branch called `origin/}__test_syntax_error_in_simpack_settings`. I wanted to create a tracking branch for it.

I had to type:

```
git branch }__test_syntax_error_in_simpack_settings origin/}__test_syntax_error_in_simpack_settings
```

I didn't have autocompletion on the first argument, only on the second. I don't like typing. Is there a faster way to do this? The main barrier is having to type the name of the new local tracking branch. Is there a way to tell Git, "create a tracking branch with the same name as `origin/whatever`?"

Comment: Sidenote: you seem to have very unusual branch names that might create problems in shells unless properly escaped. Consider renaming your branches, to save yourself some typing and problems the easy way (the lowhanging fruit :))

Comment: What kind of problems could this cause?

Comment: Since shells may give special meaning to e.g. '}' (as my very tip precisely highlights) you'd have to escape it in varying conditions. The same goes for perl and sh; git being partly written in perl/sh script _and_ subcommands specifically allowing the use of shell script within format specifications (see `man git-for-each-ref` for elaborate examples) means that you will be requiring extra vigilance at many points. You can save yourself the complication (and the awkward typing...)

Comment: Also, your local branch does not have to have the same name as the remote one.

Comment: Also if you use the git prompt which includes your branch name, that'd be *awful*. And it'd take up the whole width of the space for the commit subject in `gitk`. And... it's just ugly!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
git checkout -t -b whatever origin/whatever
```

or short

```
git checkout -t origin/whatever
```

Something to read: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout

Comment: Your 1st suggestion is pointless, it's as long as what I use. Your 2nd suggestion fails with two errors.

Comment: @cool-RR: Dont know, why you think its pointless. You need to type this one only once, because the newly created branch `whatever` will track the remote one and as far as I understand this is, what you want. Later you only require `push` and `pull` to interact with the remote counterpart. However, the second one works fine for me. What errors do you get?

Comment: I now fixed your answer to add the "-" and now it works. Your 1st result was pointless because the point of this question was to do it succinctly, i.e. typing as little as possible. Anyway, your second suggestion is great.

Comment: You don't need the `-t` in the first case.

Answer (score 5):

I'd do this in bash:

```
git branch {,origin/}}__test_syntax_error_in_simpack_settings
```

Sidenote: you seem to have very unusual branch names that might create problems in shells unless properly escaped. Consider renaming your branches, to save yourself some typing and problems the easy way (the lowhanging fruit :))

Comment: `git checkout -t origin/whatever` also checks out the branch, which is what I usually want to do, so I'd personally consider it superior.

Comment: me too :) I thought at that time that you weren't having the -t switch in your version of git (as per my now-deleted comment)